# image tap recognise position tapped iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiimage, ios-autolayout

[image: image wheel]

I have an image like this and i want to show the detail on tapped on each block, or to navigate to another page. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**[OBShapedButton](https://cocoapods.org/pods/OBShapedButton)**

OBShapedButton is a UIButton subclass optimized for non-rectangular button shapes. Instances of OBShapedButton respond to touches only in areas where the image that is assigned to the button for UIControlStateNormal is non-transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tapgesture in particular image . then open new view controller class you want to show the detail.

Comment: points(x,y) returns from `UITapGestureRecognizer` differs while in auto-layout

Comment: First you can set UIImageView in each block , then after set UITapgestureRecognizer.